# Reporting data dredging in a study

Tags: publications, data, statistics, publication-bias

During a statistical analysis of a study, I found an interesting relationship between two variables that was not part of the original hypothesis. It is, however, clinically interesting and I want to report it in the study.

I've never seen a medical study in which authors admitted to data dredging although I do know it's prevalent. I'm confident enough in my study and methods that I'm willing to admit to it.

What would be the best way to do so in a manuscript? Would I include all the information of the dredged variable such as p-values and confidence intervals, but put a note that this hypothesis is based on the data?

Comment: Why not consider a second paper?

Comment: @Buffy That doesn't really solve the p-hacking problem.

Comment: @BryanKrause, perhaps not, but it lets you focus on one thing at a time. The "problem" of finding things in data already collected is that your data may prejudice your way of thinking. But that issue is separate from the current paper.

Comment: @Buffy Yes but that has nothing to do with whether the analysis is in the current paper or a separate one. Putting it in a separate paper doesn't change that the analysis was unplanned and doesn't provide any control for type I errors. Sure, it's possible that a separate paper is appropriate, but I think it's highly unlikely that this incidental finding would stand on its own, and the OP would like to publish it.

Comment: Rather than a second paper, a second study, with adequate power, may solve the problem.

Comment: Does the result hold when you adjust your p-value for multiple comparisons?  If you apply a conservative method like a [Bonferroni Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction), that should dispel most accusations of p-hacking.

Comment: @ReputableMisnomer: that approach is unquestionably superior when data is free.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that goes into the early part of a grant application for funding a study to follow up on that observation and properly test the hypothesis.

Comment: You could write a 2nd paper but you would have to aquire a new data set. Even then, blinding would probably be best seeing as we can get incredibly biased when we think we're right.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes. I would have a separate section of your paper entitled something like "Further exploratory analysis", report what you did and what you found, and note that until a study has been design to specifically test your hypothesis, it remains a hypothesis, but suggest that it might be an attractive target for further study.

Comment: +1. Exploratory data analysis is fine, and hypotheses that are tested in studies don't appear out of the blue and there's nothing wrong with generating hypotheses. It only becomes *data dredging* when hypotesis generation and testing are mixed inappropriately (claiming *confirmation* for what is actually HARKing).

Comment: I don't know about medical papers but in computer science there is often a "Future Work" section which would be very appropriate to mention something like this.

Answer (score 16):

My best advice is to be very upfront about the fact that

1.) You found some relations in your data that were not apart of your original hypotheses you were interested in testing.

2.) These results relations were still interesting enough to share, although the evidence should be taken with a grain of salt.

Because these relations were found spuriously, the evidence is not as strong as if they were the original hypotheses of interest. When writing this in your results, it's important to reflect this.

In **my** opinion (as a PhD in statistics, for what that's worth), I'd include *unadjusted* p-values and confidence intervals, and label them as such; "p-value (without adjusting for data exploration): 0.0013". Thus the reader isn't in the dark about your interesting discovery, but also is not misled about the strength of the evidence.

On a pragmatic note, note that this means this previously unhypothesized finding **alone** is unlikely to be sufficient for publication, as one could make the argument that the strength of evidence for this finding is not particularly strong. But hitching this result onto the published paper seems quite reasonable if that connection has the potential to be interesting other researchers in the field. One of my professors referred to this type of exploratory data analysis as "hypothesis generating" rather than "hypothesis testing".

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the advice I give when I get these sorts of questions. +1.

Comment: doesn't the size of the dataset factor into this? If it's a very large dataset it is less likely to be spurious? E.g. I have access to a million medical records and browse around, and find a very strong link between two variables. That's not the same as a study done on 46 mice.

Comment: @jiggunjer No, it doesn't. The sample size influences whether a particular correlation is flagged as significant at a particular threshold. But do enough tests and you'll find spurious correlations, at any sample size.

Comment: @Sneftel: actually, it's more complicated than that. What you say is true if you are looking at a dataset in which there aren't really any true correlations. Hopefully, researchers aren't wasting time collecting large datasets where in truth, nothing is related! Now, if you have a mix of true relations and near zero relations, the larger the sample size, the more likely the true relations will rise to the top. So in that context, sample size *does* matter.

Comment: @CliffAB it is even more complicated as you are also likely to look for more relations in a larger data-set. Both because it is possible, and also because the effort of collecting the dataset might otherwise be seen as wasted.

Comment: @CliffAB what you are saying is that more of the same quality of data gives higher power, which says nothing about the issue of false positives.  As others have said dataset size does nothing to save you here.  What is far more important is how the data was collected and the quality of it.  You could have a dataset with 1500 registered voters and 10,000,000 registered voters and have the smaller dataset be a far better predictor.

Comment: @eps: "what you are saying is that more of the same quality of data gives higher power, which says nothing about the issue of false positives.". True, but the larger the dataset, the more likely the "most significant" correlations are to be real. You are looking at the rate of false positives alone, but if your data set is larger, true positives will show up with higher frequency. Thus, with a larger dataset, a positive is more likely to be a true positive than a false positive.

Comment: larger dataset == more rows, assuming columns fixed. And while I agree that data quality is very important (who cares if you are efficiently estimating a very biased estimator), that's a bit of an orthogonal issue at the moment

Answer (score 2):

This should be fine, so long as you're doing appropriate multiple hypothesis correction. Note in your manuscript what types of exploratory variables you evaluated for association, and how many of them there were. If your p-value is still significant after multiple hypothesis correction, that means there's still a stronger association than you'd expect by chance alone, which makes it an interesting variable.

If you only report the interesting variable and don't mention the other 1000 variables you tested, you could be rightly accused of p-hacking, which occurs when someone ignores "researcher degrees of freedom" to inflate the significance of their result. There's nothing inherently wrong with testing exploratory variables, you just have to do it in a responsible manner. Pre-selecting variables of study is essentially just a means of using prior knowledge to get around multiple hypothesis correction.

[Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/882/)

Comment: "so long as you're doing appropriate multiple hypothesis correction": though it may be impossible to do that as OP may not be able to exactly or even roughly quantify the number of hypotheses tested. Still it would be possible to report what exactly was done and what was observed.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica I can't think of a situation where you wouldn't have any idea how many hypotheses were tested - presumably you'd have some list of p-values from which you can select the significant ones, so your number of hypotheses is just how many test statistics you computed. Can you give an example of a situation where the correction factor is completely unknown?

Comment: I often don't even know how to meaninfully calculate p-values for "interesting observations": I'm chemometrician and spectroscopist. My data typcially has a lot of structure (as in clustered aka hierarchical data), and I can show (validate in the analytical-chemical sense) that I get meaningful predictive models. Say, by PLS after some domain-specific pre-processing. I also have some hard physics and chemistry (external knowledge) in my favor with such modeling setup. This allows me to some extent to interpret e.g. the model coefficients wrt. chemistry and allows hypothesis...

Comment: I don't know why, honestly, but in medicine, there is a ton of retrospective cohort shotgun studies with a lot of variables but rarely do I see the authors adjust their p-values. Often this is followed by "...to protect from type-2 errors".. To be fair often small studies cannot adjust their p-values because it would be impossible to draw any meaningful conclusions, and some specialties are indeed small with a small amount of specific patients.

Comment: ... generation in the sense that it may be interesting to study whether this and that substance does play a role in $application, or I may be able to say that this or that model coefficient may reflect that known chemical relationship. But absence/presence/concentration change of a substance isn't the only thing that can cause a particular model coefficient, and I have "hard physical" correlation between certain coefficients. Meaning that a substance may be highly significant, but each of the corresponding coefficients may not be. Bottomline is: a model set up for prediction may suggest...

Comment: ... hypotheses to test in further studies, but may not be the means of choice for testing said hypotheses. (AFAIK, also the analytical [in the maths sense] framework available for PLS, PCR & Co. still needs row-wise independence - which I've never encountered outside textbook/labwork practicum experiments)

Comment: @Paze The "why" is mostly because that's the data that can be collected at a single center without needing to apply for external funds, done on physician/resident free time. It's certainly fine to explore the biggest problem is when not all the results are published. Journals don't help much, either, because they tend to put up barriers when researchers don't find a magic p-value result in an underpowered study, which makes future meta analysis difficult.

Comment: "I can't think of a situation where you wouldn't have any idea how many hypotheses were tested": Andrew Gelman has written extensively about this, calling it the "Garden of Forking Paths". As he argues, we quite often see the data, and automatically start pushing hypotheses up and down, despite not formally testing any of them. Thus, we are *informally* doing multiple comparisons, with all the same issues, when we first look at our data and then decide what to turn into a t-test, regression, etc.

Comment: And in the Garden of Forking Paths, it's nearly impossible to think "what would have I thought of as interesting if I had seen other data?". So it's essentially impossible to *really* correct for multiple comparisons if peaked at all at the data before starting the analysis.

Comment: @CliffAB pedantically speaking, we know how many hypotheses were tested - it is just such a large number that we can a priori fail to reject them all.

Comment: @emory: I'd say we don't, or at least it's not simple. Maybe we look at the data and say that there is *clearly* a quadratic relationship so we test that, or notice an obvious trend that has an outlier so we inspect that outlier and remove it, etc.

Comment: @CliffAB I will agree that it is not simple.  However, the title "Garden of Forking Paths" (I did not read the article) suggests to me that the hypothesis count is 2^{number of forks}.  I can usefully approximate it as infinity.

Comment: @emory: operationally, that approximation accurate enough :). Sorry to keep driving on this, but Gelman's point on the topic is that *we are not aware of the number of forks*. When we look at the data, we are not aware how many possible paths ("oh, this needs a log-transformation", "clearly these terms are interacting!", etc) we could have walked down had the data looked different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe talk to your supervisor about it. I had something similar in my data set and it turned out that it was something that was not significant, as in it was the exact relationship a more experienced scientist would have expected to see, so I would be stating the obvious.